# Adjusting the y axis of chart if the value in the series is greater than 1000000 using macros

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a code which develops a chart using macros in excel. The input to the chart are different variable. Excel automatically adjust the axis but, i want to modify the code such as  if the input series is greater than 1000000 (1 million) then the axis is changes to millions and displays as '1' instead of 1000000

```
'This is the code i'm using to generate the chart
'counting total rows
lr = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'counting total columns
lc = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

   Set chtRng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lr, LC))
   Worksheets("sheet1").Activate

'Deleting the current chart (PS: If you could suggest a way to update the
'input values and refresh the chart rather than deleting the chart and 'adding a new one)

   For Each chtObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    chtObj.Delete
    Next

  'Adding new chart
   With ActiveSheet.Shapes
   .AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
   End With

    With ActiveChart
         '.Axes(xlValue).DisplayUnit = xlMillions
         .SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
            With ActiveChart.Parent
            .Height = 250
            .Width = 450
            .Top = 20    ' reposition
            .Left = 280 ' reposition
            End With
         End With

 'I tried using the following code but it doesn't work.

  If xlValue >= 1000000 Then
         With ActiveChart
       .Axes(xlValue).DisplayUnit = xlMillions
       End With
       Else
       End If
```

Any kind of suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change axe format using :

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "##,###0,,\M"
```

So , you could replace the end of your code by :

```
maxvalue=Application.WorksheetFunction.Max( chtRng) 

If maxvalue>= 1000000 Then  ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat ="##,###0,,\M"
```

more info in axis formats in this link:

https://www.excelanytime.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=121:custom-number-formats-date-a-time-formats-in-excel-a-vba-numberformat-property&catid=79&Itemid=475

hope this helps